# Hide a dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to hide a dropdown after I select something from it, but keep it there for me to hover over again later.

My current code:

```
<div class="navbutton_container">
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Title</p></button>
    <div class="nav_dropdown">
        <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content1</p></button>
        <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content2</p></button>
        <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content3</p></button>
        <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content4</p></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.navbutton_container > .nav_dropdown {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
.navbutton_container:hover > .nav_dropdown {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

After I select any button in this, I would like the dropdown to temporarily disappear so it's out of the way until they stop hovering over it. After they move off, I would like it so they could move back on and have the :hover property to work again.

If you think there's a better structure, I'm 100% open to changing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that will use a combination of adding classes and detecting mouseouts to acheive the goal

```js
function someFunction() {}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.navbutton_container').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    let targ = e.target.classList.contains('navbutton_container') ? e.target : e.target.closest('.navbutton_container');
    targ.querySelector('.nav_dropdown').classList.remove('hold');
  }))
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.closest('.nav_dropdown')) {
      e.target.closest('.nav_dropdown').classList.add('hold')

    }
  })
})
```

```css
.navbutton_container>.nav_dropdown {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbutton_container:hover>.nav_dropdown {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.navbutton_container:hover>.nav_dropdown.hold {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbutton_container">
  <button onclick="someFunction()" class='toggler'><p>Title</p></button>
  <div class="nav_dropdown ">
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content1</p></button>
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content2</p></button>
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content3</p></button>
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content4</p></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbutton_container" style='margin-top:100px'>
  <button onclick="someFunction()" class='toggler'><p>Title</p></button>
  <div class="nav_dropdown ">
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content1</p></button>
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content2</p></button>
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content3</p></button>
    <button onclick="someFunction()"><p>Content4</p></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay that works great. However, I forgot to mention that there are several .navbutton_containers for multiple pages of my website. Should I run the function you gave as a part of the someFunction(), or is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: @tsaxking answer updated to be scalable to N number of dropdowns.

Comment: This worked! You're the best, my apologies for not responding sooner. Had to do some stuff for a minute. Thank you so much!